# Large scale selenium automation project fails when multiple suites are running all together

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am working in a large scale project automation with Selenium where multiple test suites are available. When a single suite is running, it works fine. But when all suites are running all together it behaves abnormally. Sometimes shows element not found, noSuchElementFound etc though all suites works fine when run independently.

```
Project structure
    Main Suite
        - suite 1
        - suite 2
        - Suite 3
    Suite 1
        - LoginTestCases
        - DashboardTestCase
    Suite 2
        - abcd
        - abcd
    Suite 3
        - abcd
        - abcd
    Implementation
        - Util.py
        - Login.py
        - Dashboard.py
```

Tried with firefox/chrome browser head/headless options. But no luck. Full project running fails every time. Needs run failed cases again.

Python is used as automation language.

Is there any way around that can make sure full project run will be successful as all single suites runs successfully?

Comment: What does all running together mean, 2 or 100 concurrent browsers? Can you test environment handle 10-100 parallel runs at the same time?

Comment: What you mean by run together ? Run parallel or one by one ?

Comment: Let's say, 3 suites available. I want to execute suite 1, suite 2, suite 3 consecutively, not parallel. In this case, some testcases are failed. I have used wait functions but no luck. 
To solve this problem, 10~100 parallel runs at the same. It's more efficient but not solve the issue. @NielsvanReijmersdal

Comment: Run one by one. @PDHide

Comment: What are the failures , is there any dependency that is being created unintentionally ? Like you expect data to be empty for suite 2 but first suite left over some data that causes test 2 to fail?

Comment: Which project , which language binding do you use

Comment: No, all data of suite 1 is cleared before moving to suite 2. All dependency is removed.

Comment: which programming language you use?

Comment: python used as programming language.

Comment: Can you share the error logs. Issues which may be: 1. Memory issues 2. Test framework maxtime runtime expiration which can be controlled from config file. 3. Other process/program killing your thread. Logs can help to narrow down the issue